# How can I discriminate it as True or False according to the ouput probability in Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

## When I predict the Titanic passenger survived or not, the model output is a probability. How can I discriminate it as 0 or 1?

This is the model construction

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(inputs)
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(40, activation=tf.nn.relu)(dropout)

hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation=tf.nn.relu)(hidden1)

hidden3 = keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu)(hidden2)

out = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(hidden3)
mdl = keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
```

When I predicted the results using the trained model, I got the probability not the labels (0 or 1)

```
res = model.predict(test_data)
```

## Question:

How can I map the probability to the labels (0 or 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches to map probability to discrete class labels:

**Approach 1: When no thresholding is required**

```
predicted_class = round(res)     # rounds the probability value to 0 or 1
```

**Approach 2: When there is a need to set a threshold for classification**

```
predicted_class = 1 if res>0.5 else 0     # here threshold = 0.5 and can be fine-tuned based on the observed precision and recall scores
```

Comment: Thank you, Balraj. In this case, the threshold is 0.5. I wonder the threshold is a fixed value 0.5 or it depends on the specific task.

Comment: It does depend on the specific task, you need to take various factors into consideration such as precision & recall scores, class imbalance, etc into consideration while deciding the threshold value.